# Windows DNS server resolving specific outside domain to 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, dns, domain

I'm completely at a loss on this one.

I have a windows domain environment with 2 DNS servers, one on Windows Server 2008 R2 and one on Windows Server 2012.

Internal DNS resolution is fine. External resolution is fine as well, with one exception.

- Any time I try to resolve Facebook.com in a browser, it fails.
- This is domain wide, not restricted to my local machine.
- NSLOOKUP returns Name: Facebook.com and no ip address on my local machine and the servers
- I've checked the host files on my machine and both DNS servers.
- I've ran /flushdns.
- I went to both DNS servers and looked in the "Cached Lookups" section, and Facebook's A record is set to 127.0.0.1
- After deleting the cached lookup and trying again I got the same result.
- SSH'ing to the firewall and running DIG on the domain returns the following output:

  ```
  [HOSTNAME]:/# dig facebook.com

  ; <<>> DiG 9.9.6-P1 <<>> facebook.com
  ;; global options: +cmd
  ;; Got answer:
  ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29742
  ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

  ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
  ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
  ;; QUESTION SECTION:
  ;facebook.com.                  IN      A

  ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
  facebook.com.           890     IN      SOA     [OFFSITE LOCATION].com. 
  hostmaster.[OFFSITE LOCATION].com. 14 900 600 86400 3600

  ;; Query time: 0 msec
  ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
  ;; WHEN: Mon Jun 18 15:55:31 CDT 2018
  ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 121
  ```

The "Offsite Location" in the AUTHORITY section is a company that my company just acquired. It seems like their DNS server is responding as the authoritative server for Facebook, but I don't know enough about DNS to say for sure.

Aside from contacting them, where do I go from here?

Comment: Presumably the forwarders in your DNS server are set to the other company's DNS server. Change them to 8.8.8.8?

Answer (score 1):

Resolution was found literally minutes after posting:

I got in contact with the offsite location. Apparently, they do in fact black hole Facebook, and my DNS server had a forwarder setup to forward to them.

So they removed the entry and everything is fine.